# SQL Query to create records of dates and amounts?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like that:

```
------------------------------------
|  ID  | Amount | Date             |
------------------------------------
|  1   | 50.00  | 10/02/2010       |
|  2   | 20.00  | 10/02/2010       |
|  3   | 30.00  | 12/02/2010       |
|  4   | 70.00  | 12/02/2010       |
|  5   | 40.00  | 12/02/2010       |
------------------------------------
```

The question now is, how can I create a query that will sum the amount and group them by date like that:

```
10/02/2010 70.00
12/02/2010 140.00
```

Comment: -1 for showing no effort at all to resolve this yourself.  If you had searched for `MySQL  how can I create a query that will sum the amount and group them by date` the first hit is a tutorial on how to do this very very very basic function.

Comment: How are you sure that I have not try to solve my problem by my self ?

Comment: Because if you had then you wouldn't have posted the question here.  This is SQL 101.

Comment: Also thanks for the retaliatory downvotes.  They've been flagged for a moderator.

Comment: You are always welcome ! Because I have spend a lot of time to find out solution to my problem. But I thing something goes wrong with you ???? :?

Comment: I don't want to argue, but if you had googled for the exact sentence you put in the question, the first hit is a tutorial on this concept.  So no, you didn't try very hard at all.

Comment: Ok ! I agree ! You are genius and you know everything. In any case, maybe I don't and that's why I used that wonderfull tool !

Comment: You don't need to be a genius to know how the internet works.  Don't take it personally, I'm not saying you are stupid, just lazy.

Comment: @MerianosNikos: Nobody said you didn't try. Your question does not suggest that you did though. Exact quote was: *"for **showing no effort** at all to ..."*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [Date], SUM(Amount) TotalAmount
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lamak. I knew that was simple, but I didn't knew how to solve it :(

Comment: Another question. Is it posible to group my results based on month and not based on the wall date ?

Comment: Something like `SELECT MONYH([Date]), SUM(Amount) TotalAmount FROM YourTable GROUP BY MONTH([Date])`

Comment: Kind regards Lemak. You are just the best ;)